# Automatic layout adjustment

Tags: android, layout, resolution, adjustment

In the beginning I created my application to work on all resolutions, tested on my phone with small screen and large screen tablet.

As I had created the images for drawable-hdpi, MDPI, ldpi, each image with its resolution, he was adjusting.

However now I'm testing again on the tablet and the resolution cell is small, is only correct for the phone, she stopped to adjust the tablet increased.

Do not know if it was some setting I made in layout,
I'm using relative layout, fill_parent and wrap_content.

And in some cases put margin, and alignment, below ...

Anyone know tell me how to adjust automatically, or imagine what might be wrong?

Comment: you have images for diffenet density in different drawable, but what for different screen Size if density is same. you should create different layouts for different screen size screens...

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something about density.
Image auto scaled by os with density, as an example in lower density Image will be scaled smaller.

Comment: get density is easy. DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
  display.getMetrics(dm);
  
  double density = dm.densityDpi;

Answer (score 0):

As lulumeya said this is for sure problem of density of tablet you are using to test

For tablet instead of putting images in "drawable-hdpi" or "drawable-xhdpi" for large screens,

put them into folder named "**drawable-xlarge**" in /res folder.

This folder will be used for
large screen devices such as tablets.